# android expandablelistview null pointer exception on called activity

Tags: java, android, xml, expandablelistview

I'm having an issue getting the ExpandableListView widget to work in my app. The app is supposed to start on the main activity and after a button press it should start a new activity with the ExpandableListView showing several categories of movies. The issue I'm having is that everything works correctly when the ExpandableListView is on the main activity but it throws a null pointer exception when attempting to use it in a second activity called by a button press. I am new to java and am trying to learn but have run into this issue.

I should be clear that not all of this code is mine as I have received input and borrowed from several sources in an attempt to get this code to work and I would love to know what I'm doing wrong. I should also note that this is an entirely new package just in case I may have done something to the last one with all my changes, the error still occurs. As far as I can tell it should work. I appreciate any help, the code follows.

**Main Activity:**

```
package com.secondattempt;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startList(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

**Main Activity XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="158dp"
    android:onClick="startList"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Movie List:**

```
package com.secondattempt;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MovieList extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader,         listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                            listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
}
}
```

**Movie List XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/ExpList"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ExpandableListAdapter**

```
package com.secondattempt;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup  parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition,     childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

**LogCat**

```
04-04 05:55:35.232      865-865/com.secondattempt E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.secondattempt/com.secondattempt.MovieList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.secondattempt.MovieList.onCreate(MovieList.java:37)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

**Edit** Forgot LogCat

Comment: indicate `MovieList.java:37`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MainActivity`, you set the content view to main.xml.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In `MovieList`, you do the same thing.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Since main.xml does not contain the listview, `findViewById()` will return null;

```
expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.ExpList);
```

It should be:

```
setContentView(R.layout.movielist); // or whatever you movie list XML is called
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I overlooked that.  I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

In your `MainActivity` and `MovieActivity` you set same layout for both activities.
pls set `MovieListXML` to your `MovieActivity`

Comment: So what?  No problem.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is.  If you don't, I'll add the correct answer.